# Multiple Contexts - Right Way To Use Identity Framework Context And Entity Framework DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm learning Identity Framework wonder what is the right way to use it.
I have two context - one for Identity Framework and one for my application data (Entity Framework) - call them IdentityContext and AppContext.
The problem is that I want to store additional information for User, for example DistrictId, and it references to District entity in AppContext. So I want to ask:
 1. Is it possible to reference entities across context? Should I?
 2. Should I create another User entity in AppContext to store additional information, each user record has same ID with User in IdentityContext?
Thank you.

Comment: The entities in the two contexts are two different things, maybe they refer each other, but they will only do so in a manner like two people with the same name. What has to do with the user as a person (email, phone number) might be in the identity context, and what has to do with the user as a user in the program (settings etc) might be stored in the application database. When it comes to user identity it might be a bit safer to use guid as identifier, than int for example, when referring things that transcend contexts since guids will always be unique.

Comment: You could extend your UserIdentity and implement your new property, at the same way you could extend your context class